# Following the recent 18.04 updates, my Laptop now hangs after resume

Tags: 18.04, suspend

As per the title, Ubuntu is no longer useable for me on my HP 6930p Laptop following a recent Feb 2020 Ubuntu update. On resume after suspend, I either get a blank screen or a frozen screen, I get the same issue on Lubuntu & Mint.

I'm certain is the update, as I can install a clean system and suspend/resume works fine, as soon as the updates are applied, I get the system hang issue.

Is there any fix for this, will the Ubuntu devs reverse whatever has caused the issue?

Thanks

Comment: The Ubuntu devs will happily undo the regression...once it is reported to them with enough detail to identify exactly which update caused the problem. Step 1: Reboot into an older kernel. Does resume start working again?

Comment: In answer to the above question, the current download version works just fine, it's when the updates are applied that I get the problem, is that a different kernel? I don't know.

Comment: "The current download version" and "recent updates" are simply too vague. Since resume works for me, it likely works for them too. You must do the basic reporting work that that they cannot. A useful bug report will show the developers that it works on version X, and is broken on version X+1.  That tells them exactly where to start looking. Use `uname -r` to tell us the EXACT kernel version you have that suspend does not work. Then reboot, expose the GRUB bootloader, select an older kernel (lower version number), test the resume *does* work, and provide `uname -r` for that kernel too.

Comment: You may need: https://askubuntu.com/questions/16042/how-to-get-to-the-grub-menu-at-boot-time

Answer (score 0):

Seems that my reply to the comment is too long, so I've pasted it here as a reply.

On Saturday 22nd Feb, I downloaded Ubuntu, Lubuntu & Mint from the official websites, all 3 worked fine until the package manager made some updates which presumably also come from an official source, after the updates my Laptop either has a blank screen  on resume or the screen that was showing when I suspended the Laptop. In both cases the system is frozen. If it's not possible to work out what's on the official websites & what's in the official updates, then there's more to worry about than my Laptop. Do the updates only contain kernel changes, or are there perhaps also video driver updates. As I need my laptop for day to day use and as suspend / resume form an integral part of the daily use, I've had to move on to a Debian based distro that works just fine at the moment so I can't dig out the kernel versions. Up til now, Lubuntu has served my needs very well so it's a shame that I've had to move on. Maybe I'll come back when the next LTS version is released.

Hopefully someone else will be able to pick up on this issue and work out what changes have been released in Feb.